# How use pandas' cut method for different sections of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I scraped some data from a local website where people sell their cars. I have useful data like cars' manufacturing year, mileage, price etc. I have a Year-Price plot, but I want to colorize it according to mileage BUT so that for each year, corresponding mileages categorized in three categories.

I tried this code:

```
df.milage_year = df.loc[df.year==1395].cut(df.milage, 3, labels=['g', 'y', 'r'])
```

But I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cut'

UPDATE: Cut method works according to values! But if we want to categorize according to number of cases which method should we use?

UPDATE 2: This is my input data:

```
    mileage price       year
0   41000   70000000    1396
1   33011   73000000    1396
2   2200    81000000    1397
3   116000  45000000    1389
4   18000   71000000    1394
5   54033   65000000    1395
6   183000  42000000    1385
7   226053  44000000    1387
8   150000  45000000    1387
9   4000    78000000    1397
10  246000  42500000    1388
11  143500  35000000    1382
12  197000  40000000    1387
13  250000  38000000    1385
14  2795    81000000    1397
15  17000   40000000    1397
16  180000  30000000    1389
17  100000  61000000    1394
18  27223   71000000    1396
19  140000  49500000    1388
20  65500   71000000    1396
```

And my expected output is a new column named mileage_year that has three values: 'g', 'y' and 'r' and these values allocated to 'mileage's of each 'year' so that on-third of cases with higher mileage get 'r' and one-third of cases with lower values get 'g' and remaining one-third cases get 'y'

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful

Comment: also something like `pd.cut(df.loc[df.year==1395,'milage'], 3, labels=['g', 'y', 'r'])` may be.

Comment: `cut` is not callable on an instance of a data frame. I know it's old to refer people to the docs but this is just one of those cases http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But the problem remaining is that this code puts a NaN in other rows! So only the last years column has correct information.

Comment: df.loc[df.year==1395,'milage_year'] = pd.cut(df.loc[df.year==1395,'milage'], 3, labels=['g', 'y', 'r']) this worked! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide input data and expected output, that is how this type of questions should be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group by` and then `apply` the `qcut` like:

```
df['mileage_year'] = df.groupby('year').mileage.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3, labels=['g', 'y', 'r'], duplicates='drop'))
```

Comment: Thank you. But cut does something different. It cuts range of data into, say 3, subseries. But what I want is that to cut according to number of cases. Let me explain by an example: Suppose we have these values for mileage of year 1392: [190000, 185000, 180000, 170000, 165000, 150000, 110000, 95000, 10000] This code will give us: ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'y', 'g', 'g'] While I want: ['r', 'r', 'r', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'g', 'g', 'g']

Comment: ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([252000, 252000, 252000, 252000]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Comment: You can add `duplicates='drop'` to the qcut function

Comment: Actually I did: ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges

Comment: See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22669 for that: `drop` does not work well with `labels`. :-(